# Java, Swing, Awt - Draw a Rectangle on an image and keep it visible

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to open an image, to draw a rectangle on it (mouse DraggedEvent) while mouse is dragged and to draw the final rectangle when the mouse is released.

I achieve to draw the rectangle while dragging but I'm not able at the moment to collect the coordinates of the final point to draw the rectangle and to stock his data. Do you have any ideas to improve my code ? (Add an image in the background, that keeps rectangles on it even when resized even if several are drawn on it)

I guess mousReleased Event could help me, but I'm not sure how I should use it.

Edit : After a first rectangle being painted, I want it to remain visible if I draw a second one.

```
package selectZone;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Rec extends JFrame {

    public Rec() {
        super("rectangle");
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pane = new Pan();
        add(pane);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Rec();
    }

}

class Pan extends JPanel {

    private Point origin;
    private Point end;
    private Point endFinal;

    public Pan() {
        MouseAdapter adapter = new Lis();
        addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
        addMouseListener(adapter);
    }

    class Lis extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            end = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            origin = e.getPoint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e, Graphics g) {
            endFinal = e.getPoint();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            int x1 = (int) (origin.getX());
            int y1 = (int) (origin.getY());
            int x2 = (int) (endFinal.getX());
            int y2 = (int) (endFinal.getY());
            g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        if (origin != null) {

            int tmp;

            int x1 = (int) (origin.getX());
            int y1 = (int) (origin.getY());
            int x2 = (int) (end.getX());
            int y2 = (int) (end.getY());

            if (x1 > x2) {
                tmp = x1;
                x1 = x2;
                x2 = tmp;
            }
            if (y1 > y2) {
                tmp = y1;
                y1 = y2;
                y2 = tmp;
            }

            g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Don't override `paint`, use `paintComponent` instead, and make sure you're calling `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting, you'll find it generates less issues

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `mouseRelease` event.  The `origin` and `end` are already set in such away that if you call `repaint`, the rectangle will be painted anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to open an image, to draw a rectangle on it
>
> After a first rectangle being painted, I want it to remain visible if I draw a second one.

Keep an ArrayList of Rectangles to paint. Then in the paintComponent() method of your component that displays the image you iterate through the list to draw the rectangles.

Check out `DrawOnComponet` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example to get you started.

The example just draws the rectangle, so you will also need to draw the image. Or you could extend JLabel, so the label paints the image and then you just draw the rectangles.

Comment: I see your point thanks, but when I add the image, I can't see the rectangles I'm drawing. How could I fix that ?

Comment: You don't "add" the image to the panel. You draw the image and the rectangles in the same paintComponent() method of the panel. So you draw the image first and then draw the rectangles next so they paint over top of the image